# Disable code popup in Visual Studio references

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I use visual studio to lookup all references to a specific type, and I have my mouse anywhere in the "references" window, a (dumb) code window pops up blocking my view to a number of results.

I find this popup very annoying and disruptive in my concentration and would like to turn it off. But I haven't found a way in the menu. I've tried searching online, but it's hard to impossible to find a result (searching on something like "disable code popup in visual studio" will gives 99% visual studio **code** results.)

*If* it can be disabled, which option should I change?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it can be disabled. If you'd like to see this as an option, you should open a feedback ticket via _Help | Send Feedback | Report a problem_. If you link it here and @ me I'll make sure it gets to the right team internally.

Comment: IS switching to the list view an option? Doesn't look as pretty, but hovering over the references won't show the popup.